# How to provide the list of diff between 2 lists

Tags: matlab

I have 2 cells

```
exp = {'test','tat','toto'};
act = {'test','toto','tat','pto'};
```

and would like to check these lists are equal. How could I provide the list of differences when they don't have the same number of elements?

Comment: Would you want a 3x4 result in your example? Or which size?

Comment: @LuisMendo : I would like to get the list of differences , here for example I've converted  these cell to a char and want to compare and get the list : 'pto' here in my example

Comment: @lola: According to your comments on the answers: "*33x19char and 34x19char*", "* a diff betwwen these 2 char*", I guess you are doing `char(exp)` to convert the cell of strings to a `char`-array. This will generate a matrix of characters and fill the empty parts with spaces.
That is NOT what you should do! Keep the strings inside a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `setdiff` the order of the input matters.  `setdiff(A,B)` returns a list of entries in `A` which are not in `B` **only**, it does not return those entries in `B` which are not in `A`.

```
exp = {'test','tat','toto'};
act = {'test','toto','tat','pto'}
setdiff(exp,act); % empty because there is nothing in exp which isn't in act
setdiff(act,exp); %returns 1 x 1 cell, 'pto'.
```

Instead, use `setxor(A,B)`, which returns values not in the intersection of `A` and `B`. Order of inputs doesn't matter:

```
exp = {'test','tat','toto','pta'};
act = {'test','toto','tat','pto'};
setxor(exp,act) % returns 'pta','pto'
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, use[`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html); see the documentation, there is an example on exactly what you want to do.

**EDIT**

Explanation is needed about `setdiff`. According to the documentation:

> C = setdiff(A,B) returns the data in A that is not in B.

This sentence must be understood exactly: it returns the data of A not in B. So `setdiff` is NOT symmetric with its arguments! For your problem, if all elements of A are in B, even if B is bigger, the result set is empty.

To get the differences between two sets, in other words you want a symmetric function wrt their arguments, Matlab offers another function, [`setxor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setxor.html):

> C = setxor(A,B) returns the data of A and B that are not in their intersection (the symmetric difference).

Comment: it returns an emty strings whereas I have a diff betwwen these  2 char

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setdiff command.

```
exp = {'test', 'tat', 'toto'}; 
act = {'test', 'toto', 'tat', 'pto'};
diff = setdiff(exp, act);
```

You can find it in the documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html?refresh=true

Comment: I've already tried with this but not working :it returns anpty string and matrix

Comment: I've converted these variables into char before : exp and act are 33x19char and 34x19char then the diff gives an empty string whereas there is a diff